# How do you do beautiful reports when testing with Selenium under Perl?

Tags: perl, selenium

Selenium has some nice additional libraries, as long you are using Java to write your tests, e.g. [LoggingSelenium](http://loggingselenium.sourceforge.net/). However, these are not usable if you are writing in Perl. How do you normally do proper reporting, possibly with screenshots after every significant step etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Not an ideal answer but have you looked at the [Java module on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~metzzo/Java-4.7/Java.pm)? You could then use the original Java Selenium libraries such as LoggingSelenium to do your reporting. You'll need to run a Java server with the jar provided by the CPAN Java module (but if you're already using Selenium...)

You could also try [Java::Import](http://search.cpan.org/~rusekd/Java-Import-0.03/lib/Java/Import.pm) which might avoid the need to run a server.

Answer (score 0):

[TAP::Formatter::HTML](http://search.cpan.org/~spurkis/TAP-Formatter-HTML/) produces [nice-looking html reports](http://www.spurkis.org/TAP-Formatter-HTML/test-output.html). It does not do screenshots, though.